# How to learn Netsuite SuiteScript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have worked on Net-suite Suite Talk web services.Now i want some customization on my account using suite script.

I am adding checks to Net suite and check have some items.I want to add those items to deposit section.

user will select the check from drop down on Deposit page. 
List of item  will be displayed and user can check those to upload to deposit section.
How can i do that and how can i learn suite script to complete this task?

Thanks in advance.
HItesh Kumar

Comment: have you try it own? please ask this question in 
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to learn it is to RTFM.  Although the SuiteAnswers documentation is far from being the best, it is a good place to start.  After that, read the API file & get to know the API.  Once you have a good, practical understanding of the APIs, then work with the code in the debugger.

Aside from that, you would need to add your current code in your questions, and the errors that you are receiving.

Answer (score 0):

Those could be useful however if you try to learn SuiteScript 2.0 which I recommend because SuiteScript 1.0 will no be longer supported, then the API Doc is not very useful because the examples are very short and even with errors.
The best resource I found so far is:
https://stoic.software
Very professional guy with good knowledge, expertise and good prices.

Comment: My YouTube channel is a good place to start: https://www.youtube.com/c/StoicSoftware